# How is the accuracy of an operation amplifier measured?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, signal

I am using the AD8544 op-amp in a two stage filter on an infrared phototransistor analog signal. I am applying a very high gain to the signal (x500) and as a result sometimes the intrinsic variations of the op-amps are giving a wide range of resulting values. I want to have more consistency without lowering the gain. I could change the op-amps in my filter, but dont know how to determine which ones will give me more consistency.

Thank you!

Comment: Please share your circuit schematic. Without that it's hard to be sure (although we could make some guesses) about which op-amp parameters are most critical to you.

Comment: There are specific parts for light detectors… look for transconductance amplifiers. Also it depends on what's your issue: gain? offset? noise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally gain and offset voltage at DC and GBW for AC characteristics. The AD854x series has very low input bias (and offset) current so that's unlikely to be an issue in a well-designed circuit unless you are using extreme high values of feedback resistance.

For example, with an offset voltage as much as +/-7mV and a DC gain of 500 could lead to zero-input output voltage between -3.5V and +3.5V, which exceeds the power supply range of that chip. An AC-coupled circuit may be able to avoid most of that variation if the circuit does not need to work down to DC.

If you provide a complete **schematic** of your circuit and some indication of the **input signal frequency range and voltage range of interest** we may be able to suggest improvements to the circuit or to other amplifiers.